# ASP.NET: Overriding Content-Type Header

Tags: asp.net, http, http-headers, iis-7.5, kml

I am running a set of **ASP.NET** pages on **IIS 7.5, Windows 2008 R2**. I do *not* have access to the ASP.NET source code.

Each of these pages is emitted with the default `Content-Type` header:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

However, these pages are producing **KML** and as such should instead be emitting this `Content-Type` header:

```
Content-Type: application/vnd.google-earth.kml; charset=utf-8
```

I tried to **override** the default `Content-Type` header in **IIS Manager** as follows:

***Default Web Site*** => ***Application*** Folder => ***IIS*** Group => ***HTTP Reponse Headers*** => ***Add***:

```
Add Custom HTTP Response Header
 Name: [Content-Type]
Value: [application/vnd.google-earth.kml; charset=utf-8]
```

After doing so, the `Content-Type` header was changed but not in a desirable way:

```
text/html; charset=utf-8,application/vnd.google-earth.kml; charset=utf-8
```

As you can see, instead of *replacing* the default `Content-Type` header, the value I provided was *appended* to the existing `Content-Type` header.

**Question:** Is there some way to override the `Content-Type` header in IIS Manager? Or, is the only solution to acquire the ASP.NET source and explicitly set the `Content-Type` header there?

Comment: Parhaps you can write and apply a [custom module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986(v=vs.100).ASPX).

Comment: @CodeCaster - Thanks for the suggestion to investigate a custom module. However, I should further clarify that I personally don't have the authority to introduce any of my own code onto this server. I plan to submit a change request to the supplier of the ASP.NET KML pages to change the `Content-Type` header produced by each of those pages.